# How to change background color of the textfield in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to change the background color of the textfield to something which is transparent. I have tried

```
 option5btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

But I want some other color. Can anyone tell me which all colors can be used in the iphone textfield's background.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Check the documentation for `UIColor` to see how to create a color with whatever alpha (transparency) value you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2f green:0.3f blue:0.4f alpha:0.50001f];
```

That's an approach I use regularly.