# iphone ipad change text field colour

Tags: uitextfield, back

please, how can I change the color of the text field background and the colour of place holder? 
I saw this answer

[here in stack, change bkgrnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837975/how-to-change-background-color-of-the-textfield-in-iphone)  
but Is not clear where to call this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2f green:0.3f blue:0.4f alpha:0.50001f];
```

shall I override the UITextField.h? where?
or where shall I change the colour?

and for the changing of the place holder, but it doesn't work!
[stack, change holder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite UITextField and do this in the init method. But I would highly recommend to do simply after you created your UITextField

```
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2f green:0.3f blue:0.4f alpha:0.50001f];
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the background of your textfield :

```
  yourTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

To change the placeholder text color :

```
   [yourTextField setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```